# Netty LoggingHandler to text file

Tags: java, logging, netty, handler

So have this little server up and running and in console I can see a lot of use full information about the network, however, I'm not sure how to write LoggingHandler to some sort of text file. Has anyone tried it ? Or is even possible ?

```
public void run() {
        System.out.println("UDP Server is starting.");
        try{
            Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
            bootstrap.group(nioEventLoopGroup)
                    .channel(NioDatagramChannel.class)
                    .handler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(Channel channel) {
                            channel.pipeline().addLast("UDP LOGS",new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));
                            channel.pipeline().addLast(new StringEncoder(), new StringDecoder());
                            channel.pipeline().addLast(
                                    new UdpServerHandler(viewModel));
                        }
                    });
            channelFuture = bootstrap.bind(port).sync();

        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("UDP listener was interrupted and shutted down");
            e.getCause();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Logging handler uses the build in logging framework to log its messages, so you can also alter its logging destination using those things:

```
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoggingHandler.class.getName());
    log.setUseParentHandlers(false);
    log.addHandler(new FileHandler());
```

While a [`FileHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html) is a quick solution to log files, it is actually rather annoying to use, duo the fact that it accepts its logging properties (like the target file) from the system properties, instead of a contructor.

So that means you have to write your own Handler to log things in the way you want to log them:

```
    Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("test.log"));
    log.addHandler(new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void close() throws SecurityException {
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // TODO: better error handling
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void flush() {
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    writer.flush();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // TODO: better error handling
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void publish(LogRecord record) {
            // TODO: Format the logrecord better
            String formatted = record.getLevel() + ": " + record.getMessage() + "\n";
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    writer.write(formatted);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // TODO: better error handling
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    });
```